# problems with the NVL and GROUP BY clauses

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running this query on sql developer, I want to count the number of all the dates REGISTRATIONS were made, and I want to use NVL2 to return YES if yes, NO if no REGISTRATIONS were made for that date.

Oracle gives me the following error "NOT A GROUPY BY EXPRESSION"

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

```
SELECT 
NVL2(FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION,'YES','NO') AS REGISTRATION,
COUNT(1),
DATA 
FROM L_TIME LT
LEFT JOIN F_REGISTRATION FA ON LT.IDDT=FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION
WHERE  ID_YEAR='2017'
GROUP BY DATA
ORDER BY DATA
```

Comment: You asks Oracle to `GROUP BY` by `DATA` column, but also requests `FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION` column with no aggregation function. So it is confused with what to do with it.

Comment: thank you very much ! I understand the mistake

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might want some kind of conditional aggregation here, perhaps:

```sql
SELECT
    DATA,
    COUNT(FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION) AS YES_CNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NO_CNT
FROM L_TIME LT
LEFT JOIN F_REGISTRATION FA ON LT.IDDT = FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION
WHERE
    ID_YEAR = '2017'
GROUP BY
    DATA
ORDER BY
    DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `NVL2` for this.  You want to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION) = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) AS REGISTRATION,
       COUNT(1),
       LT.DATA 
FROM L_TIME LT LEFT JOIN
     F_REGISTRATION FA
     ON LT.IDDT = FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION
WHERE LT.ID_YEAR = '2017'
GROUP BY LT.DATA
ORDER BY DATA;
```

If you *really* have your heart set on `NVL2()`, you can phrase this as:

```
SELECT NVL2(NULLIF(COUNT(FA.IDDT_REGISTRATION), 0),  'YES', 'NO') AS REGISTRATION,
```